# How to close the doc reading part of the IPython notebook?

Tags: ipython

In an IPython notebook, when you look at some docs with `?` or `help()`, a split frame is opened at the bottom of the screen where the documentation shows up.
While I find this useful as a guide for continuing to play with some Python code, I would like to close this spit frame when I'm done reading the docs, so to get back the screen space.
But I can't find instructions anywhere, not with Google and not in the IPython notebook docs how to do this?

Anybody knows?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Doh*, one has to click on the very slim divider line. The subframe then closes...

Answer (score 5):

You have to press the q key.
That works for me.