# Closing a doc in IPython

Tags: ipython

I am new to IPython. The first problem I faced is closing any document that I open through the `help()` command or `?` I am using Ubuntu 12.04 terminal to access IPython. I found an answer to it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10047045/2587436)

It says "one has to click on the very slim divider line"  The slim divider line must be some where. But I couldnt find it. Can anyone please help me figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean terminal IPython (`$ ipython`) or IPython Notebook (`$ ipython notebook`) ? the question you link to is about IPython Notebook which run in browser. If you don't see the divider line I'll suppose you are in a terminal, so try pressing the key `Q` which is the usual key to quit a pager in terminal-unixy-like programs.

Comment: I am using the terminal IPython. Thanks a lot the Q button worked.

Comment: sorry forgot to do that. Did it now.Thanks again